# Defining regex argument in tidyr::extract

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

I have a column containing combinations of four phrases separated by a comma and I need to split the column with `extract` function from `tidyr` package into four new columns. At the same time, I wish to keep the order of columns, and enter any new columns right after the original column, not at the end of dataset. New column should contain only one phrase from the original column, therefore the function `separate` isn't appropriate here. The `extract` function requires regex argument but I am not sure how to define it.

The column contains all combination of the following phrases:

```
"Underweight",
"Healthy weight",
"Overweight",
"Very Overweight"
```

Here are possible combinations you can get using the phrases above:

```
"Underweight",
"Healthy weight",
"Overweight",
"Very Overweight",
"Underweight,Healthy weight",
"Underweight,Overweight",
"Underweight,Very Overweight",
"Healthy weight,Overweight",
"Healthy weight,Very Overweight",
"Overweight,Very Overweight",
"Underweight,Healthy weight,Overweight",
"Underweight,Healthy weight,Very Overweight",
"Underweight,Overweight,Very Overweight",
"Healthy weight,Overweight,Very Overweight",
"Underweight,Healthy weight,Overweight,Very Overweight"
```

Here is sample taken from the column (note you can coerce variables from factor to character):

```
structure(list(routine_provided_target = structure(c(15L, 15L, 
15L, NA, 15L, 10L, 15L, 15L, 10L, 15L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 13L, NA, 
10L, 15L, 15L, NA, NA, NA, 15L, NA, NA, NA, 13L, 15L, 9L, 15L, 
15L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15L, NA, 13L, 4L, 15L, 15L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 13L, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("Underweight", "Healthy weight", 
"Overweight", "Very Overweight", "Underweight,Healthy weight", 
"Underweight,Overweight", "Underweight,Very Overweight", "Healthy weight,Overweight", 
"Healthy weight,Very Overweight", "Overweight,Very Overweight", 
"Underweight,Healthy weight,Overweight", "Underweight,Healthy weight,Very Overweight", 
"Underweight,Overweight,Very Overweight", "Healthy weight,Overweight,Very Overweight", 
"Underweight,Healthy weight,Overweight,Very Overweight"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), duration = c(27.6666666666667, 25.45, 16.1166666666667, 
16.85, 17.9333333333333, 34.05, 24.7666666666667, 32.6166666666667, 
21.55, 18.4833333333333, 0.55, 3.23333333333333, 24.3166666666667, 
0.483333333333333, 47.1833333333333, 1.43333333333333, 151.933333333333, 
33.4166666666667, 76.6833333333333, 1.1, 0.65, 1.83333333333333, 
23.1166666666667, 17.8333333333333, 2.61666666666667, 0.683333333333333, 
14.6833333333333, 8.8, 18.8, 12.8833333333333, 17.6833333333333, 
22.8166666666667, 10, 14.2666666666667, 75.7166666666667, 51.4333333333333, 
27.5833333333333, 30.6833333333333, 36.8666666666667, 23.25, 
155.716666666667, 1.73333333333333, 1.41666666666667, 0.233333333333333, 
1.85, 1.35, 25.3666666666667, 0.816666666666667, 6.71666666666667, 
0.75)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Here is the code attempting to execute what I need; however, the regex argument doesn't work properly, it does some separation but it's a mess, it should containt whole phrase:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

sample %>%
  extract(routine_provided_target, c(
    "routine_provided_uw",
    "routine_provided_hw",
    "routine_provided_ow",
    "routine_provided_vow"
  ),
  regex = "([a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z]+)",
  remove = F
  )
```

The desired output is close to the following:

```
structure(list(routine_provided_target = structure(c(15L, 15L, 
15L, NA, 15L, 10L), .Label = c("Underweight", "Healthy weight", 
"Overweight", "Very Overweight", "Underweight,Healthy weight", 
"Underweight,Overweight", "Underweight,Very Overweight", "Healthy weight,Overweight", 
"Healthy weight,Very Overweight", "Overweight,Very Overweight", 
"Underweight,Healthy weight,Overweight", "Underweight,Healthy weight,Very Overweight", 
"Underweight,Overweight,Very Overweight", "Healthy weight,Overweight,Very Overweight", 
"Underweight,Healthy weight,Overweight,Very Overweight"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), routine_provided_uw = c("Underwei", "Underwei", "Underwei", 
NA, "Underwei", "Overwei"), routine_provided_hw = c("g", "g", 
"g", NA, "g", "g"), routine_provided_ow = c("h", "h", "h", NA, 
"h", "h"), routine_provided_vow = c("t", "t", "t", NA, "t", "t"
), duration = c(27.6666666666667, 25.45, 16.1166666666667, 16.85, 
17.9333333333333, 34.05)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In the output, you can see that the extract function creates new columns right after the original column and before any columns that were already in the dataset, the order of columns is preserved.

Thank you for any suggestions on how to achieve this. The whole code except for the regex line should work.

Comment: It wouldn't work because there is a `,` delimiter that didn't specify.  also, there are spaces within words

Comment: @akrun thank you for your comment, yes, I am aware of this but I don't know the correct regex to take this into account.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want to extract specific criteria into specific columns (for example: the word `Underweight` should be extracted into `routine_provided_uw`). Using `mutate` with specific regular expressions to catch each criteria is the best way to accomplish this.

First, lets add a `duration` column to your data to show how you can get the order of columns the way you want:

```
sample <- sample %>%
    mutate(duration = c(seq_len(nrow(sample))))
colnames(sample)
[1] "routine_provided_target" "duration"
```

Now we extract the data from `routine_provided_target` into new columns and use `select` to remove the `routine_provided_target` column and move `duration` to the end.

```
sample %>%
    mutate(routine_provided_uw = str_extract(routine_provided_target, 'Underweight'),
           routine_provided_hw = str_extract(routine_provided_target, 'Healthy weight'),
           routine_provided_ow = str_extract(routine_provided_target, 'Overweight'),
           routine_provided_vow = str_extract(routine_provided_target, 'Very Overweight')) %>%
select(-c(routine_provided_target, duration), duration)

# A tibble: 50 x 5
   routine_provided_uw routine_provided_hw routine_provided_ow routine_provided_vow duration
   <chr>               <chr>               <chr>               <chr>                   <int>
 1 Underweight         Healthy weight      Overweight          Very Overweight             1
 2 Underweight         Healthy weight      Overweight          Very Overweight             2
 3 Underweight         Healthy weight      Overweight          Very Overweight             3
 4 NA                  NA                  NA                  NA                          4
 5 Underweight         Healthy weight      Overweight          Very Overweight             5
 6 NA                  NA                  Overweight          Very Overweight             6
 7 Underweight         Healthy weight      Overweight          Very Overweight             7
 8 Underweight         Healthy weight      Overweight          Very Overweight             8
 9 NA                  NA                  Overweight          Very Overweight             9
10 Underweight         Healthy weight      Overweight          Very Overweight            10
# ... with 40 more rows
```

If you want to get rid of the `routine_provided_target` column, you can use `transmute` which drops all other variables except for the ones created in that call, or use select to drop that column specifically:

```
select(-routine_provided_target)
```

Comment: Hello and thank you. Yes, I wish to "extract specific criteria into specific columns" exactly the way you suggest. I am aware of mutate approach here but did not use it on purpose because I liked the `extract` approach that puts the criteria into columns after the column they originally came from and allows `remove = FALSE` argument. Sadly, I do care about the order so I can't use `separate`.

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output? I don't understand how your desired output is different from the one this method provides.

Comment: Thank you. I've added an output (from `extract` function) I am trying to achieve here. The full dataset is lengthy and I wish to also preserve the order of columns, I did not choose the `mutate` functions as they put new columns at the end of dataset while `extract` right after the original column.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting `transmute`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with minimal hard-coding using the tidy trifecta of `separate`, `gather`, and `spread`. Separate `routine_provided_target` into 4 dummy variables by the comma, and gather this into a long data frame. Then create labels that will become the new column names—I did this using `forcats::fct_recode`, but you could setup a different way of easily relabeling this vector. Then use that new column to convert back into a wide format, with `NA`s filling in any missing observations.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  separate(routine_provided_target, into = c("w1", "w2", "w3", "w4"), sep = ",") %>%
  gather(key = key, value = weight, -duration) %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  filter(!is.na(weight)) %>%
  mutate(provided = as.factor(weight) %>% fct_recode(uw = "Underweight", hw = "Healthy weight", ow = "Overweight", vow = "Very Overweight") %>% sprintf("routine_provided_%s", .)) %>%
  spread(key = provided, value = weight)
#> # A tibble: 25 x 5
#>    duration routine_provided_hw routine_provided_ow routine_provided_uw
#>       <dbl> <chr>               <chr>               <chr>              
#>  1      8.8 Healthy weight      Overweight          Underweight        
#>  2     12.9 Healthy weight      Overweight          Underweight        
#>  3     14.7 <NA>                Overweight          Underweight        
#>  4     16.1 Healthy weight      Overweight          Underweight        
#>  5     17.7 Healthy weight      Overweight          Underweight        
#>  6     17.9 Healthy weight      Overweight          Underweight        
#>  7     18.5 Healthy weight      Overweight          Underweight        
#>  8     18.8 Healthy weight      <NA>                <NA>               
#>  9     21.6 <NA>                Overweight          <NA>               
#> 10     23.1 Healthy weight      Overweight          Underweight        
#> # ... with 15 more rows, and 1 more variable: routine_provided_vow <chr>
```

**Edit:** As for setting up the `routine_provided_*` columns, here's a walkthrough with a sample of the weights. In the `mutate` call above, I recoded the levels of `weight` to give the levels the abbreviations you had—"Underweight" = "uw", etc.

```r
as.factor(weights) %>% 
  fct_recode(uw = "Underweight", hw = "Healthy weight", ow = "Overweight", vow = "Very Overweight")
#>  [1] vow ow  vow hw  hw  hw  uw  ow  uw  uw 
#> Levels: hw ow uw vow
```

Then I pipe it into `sprintf("routine_provided_%s", .)`, where the `.` is a stand-in for the vector I'm working on. So the string of each level replaces the `%s`, giving you, for example, `routine_provided_uw`.

```r
as.factor(weights) %>% 
  fct_recode(uw = "Underweight", hw = "Healthy weight", ow = "Overweight", vow = "Very Overweight") %>%
  sprintf("routine_provided_%s", .)
#>  [1] "routine_provided_vow" "routine_provided_ow"  "routine_provided_vow"
#>  [4] "routine_provided_hw"  "routine_provided_hw"  "routine_provided_hw" 
#>  [7] "routine_provided_uw"  "routine_provided_ow"  "routine_provided_uw" 
#> [10] "routine_provided_uw"
```

Comment: Thank you. I added `num_range(prefix = "w", range = 1:4)` as there are many other columns which I did not use in the sample I've provided.

I had no clue you can use `%>%` inside mutate function like this!

Could you please briefly explain how the `sprintf` function works there?